# Allow user to edit his own 'profile model', which has a OneToOne relationship with the user model

Tags: python, django

I am using the default User model along with a custom AgentBasicInfo 'profile model' with additional information about the user.

I am trying to give each user the ability to edit his profile model and only his own.  I am using the generic.edit UpdateView.

I am confused as to how I approach this.  I have tried a few things but gotten errors, mainly NoReverseMatch.  See my code below:

**views.py**

```
class EditBasicInfo(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = AgentBasicInfo
    form_class = AgentBasicInfoForm

    # the user want to edit this post must be owner this post
    def get_queryset(self):
        post_qs = super(EditBasicInfo, self).get_queryset()
        return post_qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

**models.py**

```
class AgentBasicInfo(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    preferred_email = models.EmailField()
    office_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    brokerage_of_agent = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_last_name
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^edit_base_info/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EditBasicInfo.as_view(), name='edit_base_info'),
```

**HTML URL tag**

```
{% url 'edit_base_info' agentbasicinfo.id %}
```

I need some guidance as to how I can achieve this.  Thank you!

**Updated views.py**

```
class EditBasicInfo(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = AgentBasicInfo
    form_class = AgentBasicInfoForm

    # the user want to edit this post must be owner this post
    def get_object(self):
        return self.get_queryset().get(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: If you need help with a specific error, you should add the error message and the full traceback to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user should only be able to edit their own profile, you can use the same url for everyone.

```
url(r'^edit_base_info/$', views.EditBasicInfo.as_view(), name='edit_base_info')
```

Then you don't need to pass extra arguments to `{% url %}`.
(I'm assuming you are not using [namespaced urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces))

```
{% url 'edit_base_info' %}
```

Instead of overriding `get_queryset`, you should override `get_object` to get the specific profile instance.

```
get_object(self):
    return self.get_queryset().get(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I made the changes as you wrote.  I am no longer getting the NoReverseMatch error but I am getting a DoesNotExist error: AgentBasicInfo matching query does not exist.  I posted my updated views.py into the main post.

Comment: There must be an existing `AgentBasicInfo` for the logged in user. You can create one if it doesn't exist, or you can create it when you create a new `User` instance.

Comment: Ahh I struggled over this for an hour.  `AgentBasicInfo` is created at the same time User is created (during registration).  I couldn't figure out for the life of me why it is not showing up, then I realized I was testing with my superuser, which I created through the cmd...  It's working now, thanks!